# Show Toast on ScanContiniously

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using mvvmcross and I've implemented the ScanContiniously method from ZXing and it works perfectly. What i want now is to let the user know what code was read by showing a toast on the screen, otherwise it wont be sure if that code scan was succesfull. This is what im trying but it just wont show anything on the screen:

```
Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, mensaje, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Also tried getting the context from the current activity like this:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity.ApplicationContext
```

But it didn't work either.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to be sure your Toast is executing on the UI thread:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => {
  Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, mensaje, ToastLength.Short).Show();
});
```